# Как можно поменять селектор во vue?

Tags: vue.js

Как можно поменять селектор, то есть вместо div чтобы стало input? На jquery примерно понятно как это сделать типо `$('div').html('<intput type="text">');`

Но вопрос как сделать это во vue? или если это не безопасно от xss не безопасно, то примерно как сделать так чтобы было нормальная реализация. То есть что я хочу сделать.

Допустим есть div и там храниться информация, так же как и в exel и все что с ним связано. Двойной клик делаешь и ты можешь поле отредактировать, как отредактировал, ты в другое место кликаешь и в ячейка данные сохраняются
Вот моя песочница https://codesandbox.io/s/pyvjxxnnvj

В модальном окне я уже реализовал двойной клик src/components/ModalComponent.vue:10, только не пойму как сделать так чтобы селекторы поменять

```
<template>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">ФИО</div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" @dblclick="editField('full_name')">{{ fullName }}</div>
              </div>
...
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="modal-default-button btn btn-primary" @click="$emit('close')">
                Закрыть
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['item'],
  methods: {
    editField(fields){
      console.log(fields);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fullName: function(){
      let item_ = this.$props.item;
      return `${item_.last_name} ${item_.name} ${item_.patronymic}`;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
...

</style>
```

Comment: Не меняй сам элемент, добавь input рядом и перекрой им стилями ячейку. после окончания редактирования обновляй div и уничтожай input

Comment: Я просто новичок, я должен добавить в data переменную input верно? или как происходит добавление dom элемента во vue?

Comment: То есть примерно так http://jsbin.com/zusokiy/edit?html,js,output ?

Comment: Да, примерно. Только до начала редактирования input скрыт, во время редактирования - поверх ячейки, в конце - опять скрыт

Comment: твой пример на jquery не делает вместо div чтобы стало input

Comment: Я только примерно показал как бы на jquery заменить. Там или html при клике или append(). Но по-моему при клике html